# Degree Sequence Problem

Tags: graph-theory

I found this degree sequencing problem interesting and tried to work it out but got stuck. I would like to find the graphs with the following degree sequence:

For $ N>4 $, the degree sequence of a set of graphs is defined as follows:

$ (N, N, N, N, 4, 4, 4, ... ) $,

where the number of $ 4's $ in the degree sequence is equal to $ (N-2)^2 $.

For each $ N $ prove that there are at least two graphs with the given degree sequence.

Prove that for each $ N $ there is only one planar graph that satisfies the degree sequence.

If there is only one planar graph that satisfies the degree sequence is that interesting or uninteresting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $N=5$ the degree sequence is $(\color{blue}{5^4}, \color{red}{4^9})$ (where multiplicities have been indicated by using exponents. The obvious planar graph with this degree is 
[image]

BUT this is not the only planar graph with this degree sequence !
[image]

Comment: A small addition to this answer: It is easy to see these graphs are not isomorphic by looking at the number of red nodes with four red neighbours, or by looking at the number of blue nodes with two blue neighbours.

Comment: Is there anything interesting about the number of planar representations for a degree sequence?